# Determining why Windows server is responding so slow?

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2016

We have Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 with a Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU17). This server is inside network *OurCompany*.  It also has IIS 10.0 that's hosting an asp.net web app.

I use this web app frequently from my work PC (also inside network *OurCompany*) but lately, I've noticed lots of `Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`.

I'm not a network admin, but how can I determine what's causing these timeouts?

I know it's not a SQL Server issue because the initial query (a filter) executed against the DB when the page loads is simple.

Is there a way to find any delays in the server or IIS? Maybe some network rules?

Comment: I would start by reviewing the Application logs on the server during the times you are noticing the timeouts. Have you looked at the Event Viewer yet?

Comment: Won't help finding a root cause. I generally (as my answer says) use Application Insights for this, that gives you a nice log including run times of sql statements. The application logs on the server will not contain ANY information without adding them in the program.

Comment: "I know it's not a SQL Server issue because the initial query (a filter) executed against the DB when the page loads is simple" is incorrect, as DB slowness can come beyond the query itself. It is impossible for you to troubleshoot such without involving all parties so you should request a call with network administrators, SQL Server administrators, and the web app developers together.

Answer (score -1):

Ask a programmer to look into it. This is not a simple config issue and must be analyzed on the program side. If you website WOULD have something like Azure Application Insights installed, there would be a log from the server side that could be analyzed - but as it stands now, you do not even provide enough information to start analyzing it.